# Decrypt AES key with RSA got invalid key length error Occasionally

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, cryptography, rsa

We encrypt the AES key through RSA method in Java on the client-side, aka android mobile phone.

```java
class Encryptor {
    private static String RSA_ALGORITHM = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";

    public Init() {
        this.rsaEncCipher = Cipher.gtInstance(RSA_ALGORITHM);
        this.rsaEncCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, public_key)
    }

    public byte[] rsaPublicEncrypt(byte[] content) {
        try {
            return this.rsaEncCipher.doFinal(content);
        } catch(Exception a) {
            //
        }
    }
}


JsonObject json = new JsonObject();

byte[] key = new byte[16];
random.nextBytes(key);

byte[] encryptedContent = encryptor.aesEncrypt(key, content.getBytes())
byte[] encryptedKey = encryptor.rsaPublicEncrypt(key);

json.addProperty("key", Base64.encodeToString(encryptedKey, Base64.DEFAULT));
json.addProperty("content", Base64.encodeToString(encryptedContent, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

And decrypted the AES key with RSA in Node.js on the server side

```js
function  decryptAes(key, cipherContent) {
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("AES-128-CBC", key, "AndroidAESEncrypt");
    let plainText = decipher.update(cipherContent, 'base64', 'utf8');
    return plainText += decipher.final('utf8');
}

function descrypt(key, content) {
    const contentBuffer = buffer.from(key, 'base64');
    const keyBuffer = Buffer.from(key, 'base64');
    const aesKey = crypto.privateDecrypt({
                    key: privateKey,
                    padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
                }, keyBuffer);;

    console.log(aesKey.length)

    const rawContent = decryptAes(aesKey, contentBuffer).toString('base64')
}
```

Most of the time, the encrypt/decrypt mechanism works well and the length of `aesKey` is 16. Occasionally, we met the error `invalid key length`  from AES decrypt, and the length of `aesKey` is 32. We try to decrypt the `contentBuffer` with the first 16 bytes of `aesKey` whose length is 32, the function `decryptAes` works well. It is so weird.

Is there anyone who met the same weird issue before?

Comment: Since you are using aes-128-cbc, the key length should be of 16 characters, but it you use aes-256-cbc then key length should be of 32 characters. If you have key length larger than 16 then pls substring the key to 16 characters

Comment: We are confused that why the 32 characters come up. On the client java side, the length of the key is 16. @Ashishssoni

Comment: can you check this function `encryptor.rsaPublicEncrypt(key)`, cause i can see you have provided 16 bytes of key but this function can be culprit since its encrypting the key later on.

Comment: @Ashishssoni, Sorry for missing some codes about `rsaPublicEncrypt`. Please find the updated question

Comment: The RSA part is a simple encryption and decryption. I don't see how it should cause this (sporadic) error pattern. How often does the issue happen? Does it occur in all environments or only in a specific one? Unfortunately, your code is incomplete and contains a lot of copy/paste errors. Thus, post an executable code so that a repro of the *unchanged* code is possible.

Comment: Agreed. The only way that PKCS#1 v1.5 encrypted RSA returns 32 bytes is if you put 32 bytes in, by the way. Maybe some old code hex encoded the key or something nasty like that. Anyway, something is going wrong, and it is not because of the code in the question.

Comment: @Topaco, Sorry for missing some information in the question. The client is various android mobile phones. Most of them work well, however, some are failed with 32 length of aesKey, and the ratio is around 0.2%. Unfortunately, until today, we fail to locate those devices which send invalid aesKey.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, Thank you very much for your update, we will dig into the source code deeper and hope something abnormal could be found.